# Image resizing using S3 and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've searched a lot and I found that a lot of documentations are related with uploading s3 direct and then invoke Lambda function.

However, it uses put object twice to resize the images.

What I would like to do is to upload image to Lambda direct with API, and then it resizes images and upload to S3.

However, I cannot find the related documents on Google. I wonder the reason and I doubt that this is good practice.

Is it better to resize images after uploading to S3?

Comment: Is your current high level architecture,  put request to API gateway endpoint with method put using lambda proxy which then resizes and places in s3?

Comment: @pkarfs Currently, my EC2 instance resizes my image and then upload to S3 using AWS SDK. My plan is to bypass EC2 image processing. Workflow: when user submit an image through input form, send binary data using POST > API gateway - and then Lambda resizes image and upload to S3

Comment: Yes very achievable you just need to use lambda as the method proxy which acts as the intermediary between submission and s3

Comment: @pkarfs Thanks for your comment! :) Do I have to use AWS API using http or is it possible to send binary data using AWS SDK in EC2?

Comment: Just be aware of max the API Gateway payload size if you go that route. By the way, what is the concern with two PutObject calls?

Comment: @jarmod I just wanted to do an optimization that reduces the amount of work it needs to do. Thank you for your comment! It helps  a lot :)